# Best way to export DB data in PHP, modify it, and import it

Tags: php, mysql, import, export

I need to export data in selected tables from a MySQL database and import it into another MySQL database with a slightly different structure. IOW, I need to modify the data between the export and import (and not just the field names).

I've tried using json_encode and json_decode and it almost works, but if all the data is not pure utf8, json_encode falls over and utf8_encode doesn't solve this.

I'm considering CSV, serialize, and generating SQL in PHP. Which of those options will give me the most reliable transfer?

Comment: As long as you can "see" both databases from a single MySQL command line, you could probably do this a lot more efficiently in straight SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was not caused by an issue with json_encode as I thought. Instead, the issue was a faulty left join.

So the answer is that all the listed methods are reliable as long as your query is formed properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use PDO to query and create an array of objects than can be directly modified in code. Then use that data to import into the other database.

The better question is why UTF-8 isn't working for you. Make sure you are using a recent version of PHP.
Also make sure you are using the `mb_` prefixed functions to maintain UTF-8 (or other multibyte) encoding.

[List of PHP MultiByte String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)

Comment: I suspect that the data is somewhat corrupted with respect to character set, although the problem fields look fine when viewed in PhpMyAdmin. In the raw JSON output, though, some are null and some are truncated.  

As for creating an array of objects, I should have mentioned that the databases are often on different servers and I'm trying to create a generic tool for making the transfer so I need to write the data to a file, move the file, and then import it. 

I'm hoping that serialize or CSV will avoid the character set issues that json_encode has.

Comment: If you are using a newer version of PHP it should already be character set aware. Serialize and jsonencode should be subject to the same character set issues. You can try using the mb_ functions to convert to UTF-8 or to convert to ASCII. What is the data supposed to look like? It may help if you can show examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can also shape the data during the export, depending on how you're dumping the data using the SELECT statement and re-ordering columns or selectively omitting some or using conditionals to change the data.  The result will still be a set of rows and columns.. as long as they match the structure of your destination, you can do a blind import.   Chances are, you're using mysqldump or something though, which isn't quite as easy. Depending on the changes needed, you could always use SQL to modify the data after re-import as well.

Since SQL is made for juggling data, that could possibly be the easiest way to deal with things rather than trying to parse a ton of stuff with PHP while it's in it's dumped format.

Comment: The trouble is that I need to make modifications based on the target DB, which can vary. I need to do most of the mods during import,  so mysqldump is not a good option.

Comment: Assuming you know the target DB when you do the export, then shaping the data in your SELECT will probably work just fine.  Unless, for some reason, you have no control over the export part.   If you're starting with a pre-dumped set of data in raw SQL or CSV or something, you might be able to use awk or sed or something in *nix to manipulate the data.  Not that you couldn't do it in PHP but there are some more powerful *nix commands that might help.